# Processing of proxy layer fails using ProxyConnectionFactory in embedded Jetty 10.0.9

Tags: java, https, proxy, jetty

I am trying to implement a Jetty based proxy using ProxyConnectionFactory
following the usage documented in the Eclipse Jetty Programming Guide.  Why do
I get garbled information fed to my handle method for a https request?

Cut down code showing issue:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConfiguration;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnectionFactory;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.DetectorConnectionFactory;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.ProxyConnectionFactory;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.SecureRequestCustomizer;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.SslConnectionFactory;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory;

public class SimplifiedProxy {
    
    static void start() throws Exception {
        KeyStore keyStore = ServerImpl.getSSLKeyStore();
        int webProxyHttpsPort = 8446;
        
        Server server = new Server();
        
        HttpConfiguration httpConfiguration = new HttpConfiguration();
        httpConfiguration.addCustomizer(new SecureRequestCustomizer());
        httpConfiguration.setSecureScheme("https");
        httpConfiguration.setSecurePort(webProxyHttpsPort);
        
        HttpConnectionFactory httpConnectionFactory =
                                                new HttpConnectionFactory(httpConfiguration);

        SslContextFactory.Server sslContextFactory =  new SslContextFactory.Server();
        sslContextFactory.setKeyStore(keyStore);
        sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePassword("");
        
        SslConnectionFactory sslConnectionFactory = new SslConnectionFactory(sslContextFactory,
                                                    httpConnectionFactory.getProtocol());
        
        DetectorConnectionFactory detectorConnectionFactory =
                                                new DetectorConnectionFactory(sslConnectionFactory);
        
        ProxyConnectionFactory proxyConnectionFactory =
                                new ProxyConnectionFactory(detectorConnectionFactory.getProtocol());

        ServerConnector serverConnector = new ServerConnector(server,
                                                proxyConnectionFactory,
//                                              detectorConnectionFactory,
                                                httpConnectionFactory);
        serverConnector.setPort(webProxyHttpsPort);
        server.addConnector(serverConnector);
        
        
        
        server.setHandler(new ProxyHandler());
        server.start();
    }
    
    static class ProxyHandler extends AbstractHandler {

        @Override
        public void handle(String incomingTarget, Request incomingBaseRequest, HttpServletRequest incomingRequest, HttpServletResponse outgoingResponse) throws IOException, ServletException {
            System.err.println("incomingRequest.getRequestURL().toString() = " + incomingRequest.getRequestURL().toString());
            System.err.println("incomingRequest.getMethod() = " + incomingRequest.getMethod());
            System.err.println("incomingRequest.getPathInfo() = " + incomingRequest.getPathInfo());
            System.err.println("incomingRequest.getQueryString() = " + incomingRequest.getQueryString());
            System.err.println("incomingRequest.getScheme() = " + incomingRequest.getScheme());
        }
    }
}
```

What I get in my handle method:

> incomingRequest.getRequestURL().toString() = http://192.168.0.36192.168.0.36:443
> incomingRequest.getMethod() = CONNECT
> incomingRequest.getPathInfo() = 192.168.0.36:443
> incomingRequest.getQueryString() = null
> incomingRequest.getScheme() = http

Note how the method is CONNECT instead of GET, the scheme http instead of
https, getPathInfo method returns the address and port instead of the path
with this repeated where the path should go in the URL and the query string is
null.

With Jetty diagnostics logged (very lengthy in full), these include the
following suggesting that the ProxyConnectionFactory is failing to detect the
proxy layer and process it:

```
2022-05-20 15:13:04.102:DEBUG:oejs.ProxyConnectionFactory:qtp1141777414-46: Proxy v1 attempting detection with 174 bytes
2022-05-20 15:13:04.104:DEBUG:oejs.ProxyConnectionFactory:qtp1141777414-46: Proxy v1 detection unsuccessful
2022-05-20 15:13:04.107:DEBUG:oejs.DetectorConnectionFactory:qtp1141777414-46: Detector [proxy] performed detection from DirectByteBuffer@42f3b620[p=0,l=174,c=2048,r=174]={<<<CONNECT 192.168.0.36:443 ...nection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n>>> */*; q=....\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00} with ProxyV1ConnectionFactory@65689000[proxy] which returned NOT_RECOGNIZED
2022-05-20 15:13:04.110:DEBUG:oejs.ProxyConnectionFactory:qtp1141777414-46: Proxy v2 attempting detection with 174 bytes
2022-05-20 15:13:04.110:DEBUG:oejs.ProxyConnectionFactory:qtp1141777414-46: Proxy v2 detection unsuccessful
2022-05-20 15:13:04.124:DEBUG:oejs.DetectorConnectionFactory:qtp1141777414-46: Detector [proxy] performed detection from DirectByteBuffer@42f3b620[p=0,l=174,c=2048,r=174]={<<<CONNECT 192.168.0.36:443 ...nection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n>>> */*; q=....\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00} with ProxyV2ConnectionFactory@441d3ddf[proxy] which returned NOT_RECOGNIZED
2022-05-20 15:13:04.130:DEBUG:oejs.DetectorConnectionFactory:qtp1141777414-46: Detector [proxy] failed to detect a known protocol, falling back to nextProtocol()
```

The above "detection unsuccessful" occurs with both a http and https request, although for http the
information supplied to my handle method is not garbled.

I am sending the request to the proxy from my client software with:

-Dhttp.proxyHost=localhost -Dhttp.proxyPort=8446
-Dhttps.proxyHost=localhost -Dhttps.proxyPort=8446

With proxy redirection removed from the sender VM command line and
proxyConnectionFactory replaced with detectorConnectionFactory in the
ServerConnector constructor, if I send a request directly to the (previously)
proxy port the parameters fed to my handle method are correct.  I therefor
conclude that the problem must be in the processing of the proxy layer from
the request:

> incomingRequest.getRequestURL().toString() = https://192.168.0.36:8446/index.html
> incomingRequest.getMethod() = GET
> incomingRequest.getPathInfo() = /index.html
> incomingRequest.getQueryString() = name1=val1&name2=val2
> incomingRequest.getScheme() = https

I can't find any similar issue from searches.  I have tried omitting the next
protocol argument from the ProxyConnectionFactory as done in some other
example code I found on the web with no change in the result.

Any ideas what I have got wrong?

Comment: CONNECT is a incoming proxy request.  Did you want to support that type of proxy? or Socks? or Proxy V1? or Proxy V2?   Btw, this is best asked at the issue tracker at https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues

Comment: @Joakim Erdfelt I was expecting jetty to strip off the proxy information and give me the underlying request so that I can decide how to process it, in the same way that without using a proxy it strips off the https layer.  So I’m not expecting to see a CONNECT, I’m expecting a GET or similar.  

It should support whichever proxy version (v1/v2) is used when my Java client or the user’s browser of choice sends a request and the JVM command line settings of proxy environment variables or the Windows proxy settings say it should use a proxy.

Comment: If you have it setup properly, a Proxy request will go somewhere else, not your Jetty server.  The CONNECT request is handled by the `ConnectHandler`.  If you want to modify proxy details, you should be using the `AsyncMiddleManServlet` and extending it to support what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have ...

- An HTTP Client
- A Proxy Server at `proxy.company.com` on port `8080`
- A Request to destination `http://destination.remote.com/resource/`

The way a proxy request works is like this ...

1. HTTP Client establishes connection to Proxy server at `proxy.company.com` on port 8080
2. HTTP Client sends details to proxy server about the destination server. This can be a variety of proxy protocols.  Example a `CONNECT` request for HTTP requests, or a Socks request for generic connections.  In your case it's `CONNECT destination.remote.com:80`.
3. HTTP Client receives from proxy server (`proxy.company.com`) an event on the proxy protocol it's using that indicates the connection to the remote server has been successfully established.
4. HTTP Client issues HTTP request for `GET /resource HTTP/1.1`, as it's now connected to `destination.remote.com` on port 80.

For your server to support `CONNECT` requests, you'll need the `ConnectHandler` in your server handler tree, near the beginning.

Your configuration, without changes, seems to support Socks proxy requests.

In all proxy request cases, your `ProxyHandler` will not receive the request.

Now, if you want to see the proxy request details, and even participate in the modification of the request headers, or request body content, or the response headers, or response body content, then you'll need to extend from the Jetty `AsyncMiddleManServlet` and override the methods that you want to work with.   For this to work, you'll need at least a `ServletContextHandler`  in your server handler tree that can hold your extension of the `AsyncMiddleManServlet`.